# Is it possible to put a textbox outsite a PivotItem?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying to build a windowsphone application and want to copy some of the UI features of the windowsphone twitter app and have a textbox on top of my pivot title rather than below.

[image]
.......................................................................................................................................................

I tried wrapping my textbox in a Pivot control

```
            <controls:Pivot>
            <TextBox Height="78" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="412" Name="searchTB" InputScope="Search" KeyDown="searchTB_KeyDown"/>
        </controls:Pivot>
```

But that did not work, could anyone share any ideas of how I may get this to work?

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to clarify what Marcin said (he provided the correct answer, I'm just adding an image and some more code). Is this what you are trying to achieve? Take a look below- and notice that the control above the Pivot control will be there even as you swipe to the next pivot item.

The image:
[image]

The code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="Temp_deleteme.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Foreground="Yellow" FontSize="35">Control above Pivot</TextBlock>
 <phone:Pivot>
    <phone:PivotItem Header="First">
            <TextBlock Foreground="Green" >Content in First</TextBlock>
    </phone:PivotItem>
        <phone:PivotItem Header="Second">
            <TextBlock Foreground="Red">Content in Second</TextBlock>
        </phone:PivotItem>
    </phone:Pivot>       
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Oh! okay I see my mistake, the entire thing is suppose to be in a StackPanel. Thanks Iris for the clearification thanks as well @MarcinJuraszek

Answer (score 0):

You should put it outside the pivot:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Height="78" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="412" Name="searchTB" InputScope="Search" KeyDown="searchTB_KeyDown"/>
    <controls:Pivot>
    </controls:Pivot>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Do this work for you? I tried this also and it didn't work I got a "Value does not fall within the expected range" error 
also shouldn't it be <controls:PivotItem> and not <controls:Pivot>